# Zend Framework 3 How Access Globle.php file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

In Zend Framework 3 i Have create on file in Config/autoload/myconfig.globle.php

```
return [
      "myvariable" => [
            "key" => "value"
      ]
];
```

i have access through this

$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');

give following error:

A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

so now how can i access this file in Controller in Zend Framework 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things here:

First of all, the service locator has been removed. Therefore, you have to create a factory for your controller, or use a [configuration based abstract factory](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/config-abstract-factory/).

Then, your files must respect the pattern defined in `application.config.php`, which means `global.php`, `*.global.php`, `local.php` or `*.local.php`. In your message your config is named `myconfig.globle.php` instead of `myconfig.global.php`.

So then:

```
final class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $variable;

    public function __construct(string $variable)
    {
        $this->variable = $variable;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // do whatever with variable
    }
}
```

Also you need a config:

```
return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            MyController::class => MyControllerFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Finally, let's make that `MyControllerFactory` class:

```
final class MyControllerFactory
{
    public function __invoke(Container $container) : MyController
    {
        $config = $container->get('config');
        if (!isset($config['myvariable']['key']) || !is_string($config['myvariable']['key'])) {
            throw new Exception(); // Use a specific exception here.
        }
        $variable = $config['myvariable']['key']; // 'value'
        return new MyController($variable);
    }
}
```

That should be about it :)

Comment: may i use this MyControllerFactory class configure in Module.php file?

Comment: You should keep the `Module.php` as minimal as possible as it is not cached on production executions. I do not however understand how you want to use a factory (some object that creates another object) in `Module.php`, this does not make sense to me. Can you detail your question?

Comment: above issue fixed. now i have another issue which is  MyController this controller class i have extend ApiController. This ApiController my custom class which is extend every controller. and ApiController extend AbstractRestfulController controller. so now when i call MyController then ApiController Call and in this ApiController i want to use Global.php file so how can i use in ApiController.

Comment: Because if i use MyControllerFactory for MyController and pass config to ApiController then i have to use every controller Constructor to pass this config object so i want to direct access global.php config to ApiController.

Comment: I would not recommend it, but the way to go in this case would be a "soft dependency", so passing the config with a setter from a [delegator](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/delegators/). This will expose you to [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) at least, and is a really bad practice.

Comment: ok but i am creating composer package for restapi and authentication so i want to access directly Global.php file in ApiController. so have you any suggestion for this how can i access?

Comment: Having a constructor calling parent in every child is the best option IMO. Really depends on the full use case I guess, but that should be another proper thread. If you create a new thread, add an explicit example.

Comment: Above issue fixed. now i have to question in TestCases that is i Have created TestController in that module i don't have to check any route check in TestCase. I have to check that in My Apicontroller Have three Method which is i have to call from TestCase So can you tell me how i write TestCase to Test only That Controller Method Working or not.

Comment: Again, different topic so you should create a new post. Comments are not effective to discuss further problems.

Comment: yes you are right. but after 4 days of new post another new post will be post so at this time i am not able to ask question from new post so i am asking you to comment.

Comment: @AnkitSolanki as a good practice on SO, you should just post a new question, and provide a link to someone that you think might be able to help you, if he is not able to answer your new post, you still have a chance of somebody else answer your post, plus your new post will be helpful for other peoples looking to solve a similar problem.

Comment: @Aamir you are right but i ask question in comment because once i ask here question then after 4 days stackoverflow again post a new question so i have to ask in comment.